# using parfor in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, parfor

I want to parallelize some part of my code in matlab. for example below part:

```
v1=[1,3,6,8];
ggx=5.*ones(15,14);
gax=ones(15,14);
 parfor i = 1:length(v1)
 m = v1(i);
 if m > 1
 gax(1:m-1,m-1) = ggx(1:m-1,m-1);
 end
 if m<nn
 gax(m+1:end,m) = ggx(m+1:end,m);
 end
 end
```

But there is an error:
    Error: The variable gax in a parfor cannot be classified.See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Do anyone knows how can I remove the error? Other useful information is that v1 is an increasing vector which doesn't contain any repeated element.

Comment: Have you tried initializing `gax` and `gay` before the `parfor`? Also I don't think `parfor` will help optimize your code in this case. You are better off using just a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Yes I have given them value before parfor. @kedarps

Comment: This seems like a sliced variable indexing issue, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html).

Comment: I know, after reading the link, I couldn't fix it @kedarps

Comment: I edited the question. Do you know how can I solve t? @kedarps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message, you must follow the [Sliced Variable rule](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html;jsessionid=0669dbd4595534575d236843ddd3).
Both `gax` and `gay` breaks rules of `Fixed Index Listing` and  `Form of Indexing`. Also, you can this example `A(i,20:30,end)  % 20:30 not scalar` as an example of not sliced variables in the document.

Therefore, you should change the all part of the `parfor` to getting a proper parallel computation. In the other words, you must design a proper parallel algorithm which you can parallelized the method, based on the loop variable.

> Type of First-Level Indexing — The first level of indexing is either parentheses, (), or braces, {}.
>
> Fixed Index Listing — Within the first-level parentheses or braces, the list of indices is the same for all occurrences of a given variable.
>
> Form of Indexing — Within the list of indices for the variable, exactly one index involves the loop variable.
>
> Shape of Array — The array maintains a constant shape. In assigning to a sliced variable, the right side of the assignment cannot be [] or '', because these operators attempt to delete elements.

Comment: "In the other words, you must design a proper parallel algorithm which you can parallelized the method, based on the loop variable". the question is how to do that

Comment: My opinion is you cann't do it here!

Comment: I forgot to tell that, v1 is an increasing vector which doesn't have any repeated element. In this case, do you know how to use parfor?

Comment: Could you update the question by adding the version 1, please?

Comment: I added more details. Do you know how can one fix this problem?

Comment: As you want update the same index of `gax` and `gay` in different thread, you can't parallelized your code using `parfor`.

Comment: Forget about gay. I edited the question. Do you know how to solve the problem now?